# pandas_udf function running in aws glue does not put objects to s3 without print function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, user-defined-functions, aws-glue

This is what I am trying to do.

SparkDataframe -> groupby -> call pandas_udf method that creates some files in s3 using boto3

pandas_udf method

```
# Pandas_UDF method
saveSNFile_schema = StructType([
    StructField('cloc', StringType(), True), # chunk file location
    StructField('aggloc', StringType(), True), # chunk file location
    StructField('trackloc', StringType(), True), # chunk file location
    StructField('sn',StringType(),True), # serial number
    StructField('len',LongType(),True), # number of rows saved
])
@pandas_udf(saveSNFile_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def saveSNFile(sndf):
    """
        Save dataframe as a parquet file in S3

    parameters:
        sndf: pandas dataframe 

    return:
        pandas dataframe
    """

    fname = sndf.iloc[0]['field1']
    sn = "%s" %(sndf.iloc[0]['tmp_sn'])
    year = sndf.iloc[0]['partition_0']
    month = sndf.iloc[0]['partition_1']
    day = sndf.iloc[0]['partition_2']

    # get the file name in Tier-3 to save the dataframe
    chunkFileLocation, aggFileLocation, tradkingFileLocation = get_ChunkLocation(fname, sn, year, month, day)

    csv_buffer = BytesIO()
    # convert pandas dataframe to parquet format
    sndf.to_parquet(csv_buffer, compression='gzip')
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

    # save the file to S3
    s3_resource.Object("S3bucketName", chunkFileLocation).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())

    # create a tracking empty file
    s3_resource.Object("S3bucketName", tradkingFileLocation).put()

    # create empty file with SN as file name
    s3_resource.Object("S3bucketName", "%s/aggregated_sn/%s" % (T3TrackingPrefix, sn)).put()

    # delete the aggregated files since we have new files in chunks location 
    rval = s3_resource.Object("S3bucketName", aggFileLocation).delete()

    # Return pandas dataframe with additional information as schema defined above 
    rdf = pd.DataFrame([[chunkFileLocation, aggFileLocation, tradkingFileLocation, sn, len(sndf)]], columns=[ 'cloc', 'aggloc', 'trackloc','sn', 'len'])


    return rdf
```

Calling the pandas_udf method

```
rdf = dataFromS3Df.groupby("tmp_sn").apply(saveSNFile)
print(rdf.show()) # <---- without this print method, udf function does not create any files in S3
```

With the `print(rdf.show())` above the method is working as expected

Without `print(rdf.show())` udf function does not send any puts to s3 bucket.

This is really strange for me. I have talked to aws support as well, they do not have a clue.

I understand the pandas_udf method is running in worker nodes hence I had to create a connection within the function to s3, but what strange is even after my notebook ran until I do some operation on the dataframe (`rdf`) it does not create the files in s3.

Answer (score 0):

`rdf.collect()` solves the problem.